# dnt see theme-resources partials htmls in a containered keycloak after deploy 'social' jar

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

Created `bio-identity-provider-keycloak.jar` - its mine plugin, based on social plugin source examples (details and link on bottom)

there are attached 2 html files

```
src\main\resources\theme-resources\resources\partials
realm-identity-provider-bio.html
realm-identity-provider-bio-ext.html
```

Files packed in a jar, as it asked on docs.

[image]
its similar as on 'social stackoverflow' plugin from main keycloak repository

jar works pretty fine, but without mine htmls.... this is a problem

My deploy scenario.

- i use keycloak docker container 19.0.2 version,
- i do uploading jar into /opt/keycloak/providers
- i do start container, also i used kc.sh build command, ... but noway doesnt help me
  on indentity providers page, i saw mine plugin but without htmls...[image]
- same problem if i do uploading jar from 'apple social','discord social' from a 'official' git,
- i saw 'htmls from `stacoverflow social plugin`', there are https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/main/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/admin/resources/partials a sources[image]

my guess its because need to 'build' themes after jar uploading into providers, currently keycloak doesnt see 'html' resources in my case

https://www.keycloak.org/extensions.html -- a link for 'apple' and 'discord' examples

please help :)

Comment: Hi, we are having the same issue, did you ever fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the admin keycloak theme v1 for those changes to be taken into account, the admin that you are working on is based of react instead of angularjs.

Go to Realm settings and in the themes tab select the admin theme 'keycloak', click save and reload your page. Then go to your IDP and your changes should be up.